# Passing a Node.js render variable to client javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, node.js

i'm currently working on a project that involves passing json object as a variable over the node.js render method. I want to pass part of this sent variable to the client side javascript. How would I do this?

Render sending method:

```
res.render('users', renderUserData);
```

JSON being sent (I JSON.stringifyied the userdata for testing purposes):

```
{ title: 'Johans Sandbox Node and Mongo Database',
  users: '[{"_id":"54dcbe726ca6812a0d64a1be","name":"name0","__v":0},{"_id":"54dcbe856ca6812a0d64a1bf","name":"name1","__v":0},{"_id":"54dcbe8c6ca6812a0d64a1c0","name":"name2","__v":0},{"_id":"54dd0546945c8fb306b20659","name":"name3","__v":0},{"_id":"54dd28a6945c8fb306b2065a","name":"name4","__v":0}]',
  _locals: {} }
```

When I use the HTML identifier: `{{ title }}` or `{{ users }}` the data shows up and prints out from the html code.

How would I go about passing the users data to the client side javascript?

Im currently using CSS for templating, with html and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [`res.send(json_data)`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send) or [`res.json(json_data)`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.json).

Comment: Won't that overwrite the render page though?